# Highmaps tooltips in drilldowned map of Slovakia

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I would like implemented names of town (Trencin, Nemsova, Ilava... ) and their tooltips together. Click on green TN block in map and check it. 
I try some solutions, but:

1. tooltip overllaps names of towns:

   ```
    useHTML: true,
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/grzwuL9g/5/ (line 47)

2. three names of towns are missing:

   ```
    useHTML: false //(default),
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/grzwuL9g/4/  (line 47)

3. give tooltip out of map, but impossible:

   ```
    positioner: function () {
        return { x: 0, y: 250 };
    },
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyUxF/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/j92p2/ in chart 
http://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/grzwuL9g/5/ (line 55)

4. giving name of town with connectors out of map: 
   http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/us-data-labels 
   http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/9Fk3a/5/ 
   I cant do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.hideOverlappingDataLabels = function() {};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grzwuL9g/16/)